# Remove specific value in array and add new updated value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to remove existing specific value in an array before adding or push another updated value. My purpose is to avoid duplicate same id and value to array. What i'm trying to achieve is when onchange triggered check if that value is existing on array and if exist remove the old one and push the update value.

```
  const [array, setnewarray] = useState([]);
     function handlechangeselected(val,id){

       var newarray = array;
       const valueToRemove = id;
       newarray.filter(item => item.id === valueToRemove);

        newarray.push({ value: val, id:id });
       setnewarray(newarray);

  }




  <select                                                                              
   onChange={(e) => handlechangeselected(e.target.value,row.ID)}                                                                                
  >

      <option value="0">0</option>                                                                             
      <option value="1">1</option>                                                                           
      <option value="2">2</option>

  </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that `filter` doesn't modify the array, but rather returns a new array. You're not using the returned array, so `newArray` is unchanged.

The other issue is that `filter` filters out out any values that return *false* from your callback, so you want your filter to return true for any items that *don't* match `valueToRemove` (in other words, `!==` instead of `===`). You can also use `.concat` to chain after `array.filter`.

Here it is, simplified a bit:

```
     const [array, setNewArray] = useState([]);

     function handlechangeselected(value, id){
       const newArray = array
         .filter(item => item.id !== id)
         .concat({ value, id });

       setNewArray(newArray);
     }
```